# Readline for windows - developing on linux

Tags: gcc, mingw, cross-compiling, readline

I am developing on linux, but still release binaries for windows.

I recently started using readline though, and that has broken my windows builds. Initially it was unable to find the header files, so I copied them to the mingw includes folder. However I still get problems linking to the library (cannot find -lreadline).

How do I get the readline library so that I can link to it in linux when compiling for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readline should just work, on Windows, I think, although you'll probably have to compile it yourself and bundle it with your program.

You'll need a replacement for ncurses though: pdcurses should do the job for you. Again, you'll probably have to build it yourself, I think.